# How to decrease this mysql query execution time

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

This is my MySQL query:

```
select en.course_instance_id, count(*) 
from user u 
inner join enrollment en on en.user_id = u.user_id 
where en.account_id=5392 
  and en.course_instance_id in (5127039, 5127040) 
  and enrollment_state='ACTIVE' 
  and u.state!='DELETED' 
group by en.course_instance_id;
```

My `user` table has `user_id` as primary key and `enrollment` table has `(user_id, course_id)` as primary key.

Basically, this query is trying to find number of user enrolled in every course_instance.

Now, for `course_instance_id` 5127039, 352438 users are enrolled and for `course_instance_id` 5127040, 1 user is enrolled.

When I am trying to run this query, it is going in timeout(it is taking more than 2 min).

I have checked indexes on both the tables and I am assuming they are used correctly. For `enrollment` table index of `course_instance_id, course_id` is used and for `user` table PRIMARY index i.e. `user_id`  is used.

Have attached snapshot of the indexes that are being used for this query :

[image: Indices usage for the above SQL query]

Comment: execute `desc analyze select...` to see the cost structure https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
select en.course_instance_id, count(*) 
from user u inner join
     enrollment en 
     on en.user_id = u.user_id 
where en.account_id = 5392 and
      en.course_instance_id in (5127039, 5127040) and 
      en.enrollment_state = 'ACTIVE' and
      u.state <> 'DELETED' 
group by en.course_instance_id;
```

I would recommend an index on `enrollment(account_id, enrollment_state, course_instance_id, user_id)`.

You could add an index on `users(user_id, state)`, but this is not really needed given that `user_id` is probably the primary key.

Comment: Thanks. This index helped in decreasing execution time by much margin.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually I think your query would be clearer like this.  The output should be the same but mysql could be happier with all of the restrictions on user on the join clause. I was not certain which table enrollment_state came from.

```
select en.course_instance_id, count(*) 
from enrollment en
inner join user u on en.user_id = u.user_id and u.state!='DELETED'
where en.account_id=5392 
  and en.course_instance_id in (5127039, 5127040) 
  and enrollment_state='ACTIVE' 
group by en.course_instance_id;
```

Comment: . . . MySQL is software that does not experience emotions such as happiness (schadenfreude might be a different matter ;).  That said, there should be no difference in filtering an inner join in the `on` clause versus the `where` clause.

Comment: After a few tests I came to the same conclusion.  I think selecting from enrollment joining to user is clearer since the query does in fact select from enrollment and not user, but that is a separate issue from performance improvement.

Comment: ..., at least not for `INNER JOIN`.  (`LEFT`/`RIGHT` might matter.)